# How to return pointer to an array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

How can a function return a pointer to an array of strings?

I have to do this without using the C's `string.h` library. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* myFunc(){
    char* result[2];

    // the strings are originally dynamically allocated with some
    // function parameters which i've omitted to simplifiy the question.

    result[0] = "abc";
    result[1] = "def";
    return result;   
}

int main(void){
    char* result = myFunc();
    printf("%s\n%s\n", result[0], result[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect two strings, but the compiler returns this:

```
error: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     return result;
```

Comment: There is a difference between returning an "array of strings" aka 'array of array of char' (`char x[][]`) (which is not possible in C), returning a "pointer to an array of strings" aka 'pointer to array of array of char' (`char (*x)[][]`), and a "pointer to the first of many strings" aka 'pointer to array of char' (`char (*x)[]`). There's also the possibility that your strings may be not arrays but pointers to char. Clarify, please

Comment: Or to simplify CF's attempt at explanation, there's no such thing as a "string" in C at all. There are characters (which are just individual bytes), pointers, and arrays. What you want to return is a pointer to pointer to char (i.e. char **).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a type mismatch.

Your function is defined to return a `char *` but you return a `char *[]` which decays into a `char **`.  This is what the warning means.

Change the return type to `char **` along with the value you assign the return value to.  Also, you can't return a pointer to a local variable, so you need to allocate the array dynamically as you stated you did in the code comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **myFunc(){
    char **result = malloc(2 * sizeof(*result));

    result[0] = "abc";
    result[1] = "def";
    return result;   
}

int main(void){
    char **result = myFunc();
    printf("%s\n%s\n", result[0], result[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char** result = myFunc();
```

but yout variable in function is automatic and it does not exist outside the function scope

```
char** myFunc(){
    char** result = malloc(2 * sizeof(*result));
    result[0] = something;
    result[1] = something_else;
    return result;   
}
```

Comment: And `malloc(2 * sizeof(*result);` should be `malloc(2 * sizeof(*result));`